# Docker container can not ping the outside world - iptables

Tags: docker, networking, iptables

exploring Docker 17.06.

I've installed docker on Centos 7 and created a container. Started the container with the default bridge. I can ping both host adapters, but not the outside world e.g. www.google.com

All advise out there is based on older versions of Docker and it's iptables settings.

I would like to understand how to ping to the outside world, what is required please?

TIA!

Answer (score 17):

If you able to ping www.google.com from host machine try following these steps : 
run on host machine:

```
sudo ip addr show docker0
```

You will get output which includes :

```
inet 172.17.2.1/16 scope global docker0
```

The docker host has the IP address 172.17.2.1 on the docker0 network interface.

Then start the container :

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:trusty bash
```

and run

```
ip addr show eth0
```

output will include :

```
inet 172.17.1.29/16 scope global eth0
```

Your container has the IP address 172.17.1.29. Now look at the routing table:
run:

```
route
```

output will include:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

It Means the IP Address of the docker host 172.17.2.1 is set as the default route and is accessible from your container.

try ping now to your host machine ip :

```
root@e21b5c211a0c:/# ping 172.17.2.1
PING 172.17.2.1 (172.17.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.211 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.2.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
```

If this works most probably you'll be able to ping www.google.com

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: OH, I have meet a question， I use the operation above， but in the container i can  not ping docker0 getway (ping 172.17.0.1).  The 【route -n】  command in container  output ：
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0

Comment: `ip addr show` is what I really needed, WSL(Windows) Docker kills me :D

Answer (score 16):

In my case restarting docker daemon helped

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 2):

If iptables is not a reason and if you have no some limitation for change containers network mode - set it to "host" mode. This should solve this issue.

Comment: Iptables is most probably always the problem. Setting the container to host mode is bypassing the real problem and could lead to more serious misconfigurations.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your existing iptables:

```
 iptables --list
```

It should show you list of iptables with source and destination details.

```
target        prot   opt    source             destination

DOCKER-USER   all    --    anywhere            anywhere
```

If it is *anywhere* for both source and destination it should ping outside IPs.(By Default its *anywhere*)

If not use this command to set your iptable(DOCKER-USER)

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for your swift response! I will test and try within 24 hours (away from setup atm). But from memory all is 'anywhere'.

Comment: Are you pinging outside IPs from inside container or from host machine? IP tables looks fine for you. Can you once try running iptables -nvL and check there too for any restrictions. And where is the server hosted ? Aws? Google? Azure?

Comment: Here's the iptables -nvL https://pastebin.com/W95ZTqDN I am pinging from within the container to www.google.com. The server is hosted in a private cloud to which I have full access. No firewall restrictions there. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to ping www.google.com from host machine, where your docker running? not from within container , from host ??

Comment: If yes , you are able to ping from host then refer/try my another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, an api docker container needed connection to outside, but the others containers not. So my option was add the flag `--dns 8.8.8.8` to the docker run command , and with that the container can ping to outside. I consider this a solution for one container, if you need for more containers, maybe other responses are better. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) the documentation. And full line example:

```
docker run -d --rm -p 8080:8080 --dns 8.8.8.8 <docker-image-name>
```

where:

- -d, detach mode for run containers in background
- --rm, remove containers if is stop (careful if you are testing and maybe you need to inspect logs, with docker logs , don't use it)
- -p, specify the port ( `<host-port> : <container-port>` )
- --dns, the container can resolve internet domains