# what could be blocking connection from docker container to external server

Tags: docker

I have an external server abc.internalcorp.com that I'm planning to connect from docker.

I tried to ping that server from host machine and it works.

```
ping abc.internalcorp.com
PING abc.internalcorp.com (172.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from abc.internalcorp.com (172.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=32.6 ms
^C
--- abc.internalcorp.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 received, 50% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 32.673/32.673/32.673/0.000 ms
```

But when I execute the same command from my docker container, I see no response. How could this be?

```
docker exec -ti docker-container bash
root@b7bdf44feb7f:/# ping abc.internalcorp.com
PING abc.internalcorp.com (172.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
<No response>
```

This ping is just a test. abc.internalcorp.com is actually a database server and I'm unable to connect to it. I can connect to other database servers though.

**Update:**
I changed bip in ~/.docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "bip": "193.168.1.5/24",
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false
}
```

But I still have the same ping issue

```
docker exec -ti docker-container bash
root@b7bdf44feb7f:/# ip addr show eth0
10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:c1:a8:01:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 193.168.1.1/24 brd 193.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Edit**
Figured out the issue. There were other networks in my docker that were having the same network subnets. Deleted them and works fine now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509604/docker-container-can-not-ping-the-outside-world-iptables

Comment: I can still connect to outside servers. Only not this one.

Comment: I assume that you might have connected the container to bridge network. Have you tried pinging the server by connecting it to host network?

Comment: yes. tried --network host. still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to do two things.

1. change the network by editing daemon.json

   {
     "registry-mirrors": [],
     "insecure-registries": [],
     "debug": true,
     "experimental": false,
     "bip" : "12.12.0.1/24"
   }
2. Delete other networks in docker which might be conflicting with the ip. You check if any other network is in the same range using

   docker inspect 'networkname'

Answer (score 0):

The range 172.x.x.x is the default range on the internal network in docker, if you are using that same range in your local network you need to specify a different one for the docker network.

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: I changed my settings to the one given in link, but I still see the issue. I ran and see that it is still in 172.xx. Not changed.

10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: daemon.json was not found in C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json. It was under <homedir>/.docker folder. Now I can see the change in container, yet it still doesn't ping

Comment: awarding bounty to this answer as it got me closer to figuring out the conflicting network

Answer (score 0):

Find the DNS with resolves `abc.internalcorp.com`. Add it as a DNS to your docker container by updating the daemon.json as below. If x.x.x.x is the DNS.

```
{
    "dns": ["x.x.x.x"]
}
```

restart docker daemon. Then try ping from the container.